# How to circumvent SSRF filter?

Tags: directory-traversal, ssrf

I am learning on Tryhackme.com how to circumvent SSRF filter.

There is a website, let's assume it is test.com. test.com has two access points. First is `/private` which is restricted, and `/new-user-account` which can be accessed by users to update their avatars. The goal is to access `/private` content

[image]

Avatars have links back to `/assets`, and when I attempt to change the avatars link to `/private` I get an error message says `/private access is not allowed`.

[image]

[image]

However, the tutorial used a trick here and circumvented the filter.

> "As you can see from the error message, the path cannot start with
> /private but don't worry, we've still got a trick up our sleeve to
> bypass this rule. We can use a directory traversal trick to reach our
> desired endpoint. Try setting the avatar value to x/../private"

[image]

I am just curious how this `x/../private` stuff works? How does the server interpret `x/../private` to `/private`? This format does not make sense for me.

Comment: Do you know how directory traversal works? Do you know what `..` means to a file system?

Comment: Yes, but I just do not know how x/../private map to the correct location

Comment: Did you try `y/../private` and `./../private`? If you know what `..` does, then this should be obvious to you. Else the answer is to send you a basic linux file system tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to the community. `x/../private` was just an example, where you need to replace `x` with another valid page... This is pretty trivial as well.